# groupby and trim some rows based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], 
               "IF_car":[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
               "IF_car_history":[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],  
               "observation":[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,3]})
```

I want output where I can trim rows in groupby with ID and condition on "IF_car_history" == 1

```
tried_df =  df.groupby(['ID']).apply(lambda x: x.loc[:(x['IF_car_history'] == '1').idxmax(),:]).reset_index(drop = True)
```

I want to drop rows in a groupby by after i get ['IF_car_history'] == '1'

expected output:

[image: expected output]

Thanks

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compare values for mask `m` by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and then use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html), and for values before `1` compare by `0`, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), but because id necesary remove after last `1` is used swapped values by slicing with `[::-1]`.

```
m = df['IF_car_history'].eq(1).iloc[::-1]
df1 = df[m.groupby(df['ID']).cumsum().ne(0).iloc[::-1]]
print (df1)
   ID  IF_car  IF_car_history  observation
2   2       0               0            0
3   2       1               1            1
5   3       0               0            0
6   3       0               0            0
7   3       1               1            2
8   3       0               0            0
9   3       1               1            3
```

Comment: My expected output is little different from your solution but thanks for your time.